From keras.models, keras.layers and keras.optimizers, Import not resolved
Just ran into one problem which is that the from keras.models, keras.layers and keras.optimizers it says import could not be resolved, do you know how I can fix this?
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import random

Unfortunately does not let me upload full code. Tried to make a chatbot using flask and keras but keras not working and the rest is perfectly working. Need this to run in order for chatbot to work. I tried all tensorflow.keras, tf.keras, uninstalled and installed both keras and tensorflow but still nothing.
Would be greatly appreciated if you have some time and are able to help by contacting, can send further code with zip via email thanks.

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout

Changed to this below, and now it's working:
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout

or (runs but still errors for some reason):
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout


No, this is not correct, messages from your IDE are irrelevant, tensorflow.python is not the right import and it might break in the future.

Even after removing python word and making to tensorflow.keras.models I get his "File "c:\Users\Ali_B\Documents\ITMB\Final year\ACareers-app\training.py", line 73, in 
training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (47, 2) + inhomogeneous part."

You solved the problem, now you have a different problem in your code.

Some keras libraries might be missing so please try this
pip install keras
pip install keras-utils
pip install --upgrade keras
pip install keras-models

you can use sudo pip install if you can,
and then give a
import keras
print(keras.__version__)

to be sure that keras is installed

from keras.api import *
from keras.api.layers import Dense

This worked for me

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
